# T-SQL script to calculate time difference between multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
EventDateTime           EventName   AppID
-----------------------------------------
2014-06-27 22:17:19     GotFocus    1000
2014-06-27 22:17:20     LostFocus   1000
2014-06-27 22:17:22     GotFocus    1005
2014-06-27 22:17:24     LostFocus   1005
2014-06-27 22:17:27     GotFocus    1000
2014-06-27 22:17:30     LostFocus   1000
2014-06-27 22:17:37     GotFocus    1005
2014-06-27 22:17:40     LostFocus   1005
```

What I need to do is to create a T-SQL script that computes the **total** duration that each app was in focus (i.e. sum of all LostFocus-GotFocus per app). So for the table above I should get:

```
Duration    AppID
------------------
4           1000
5           1005
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can we assume that every Got focus has a lost focus?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  With SQL questions, it helps if you give a name to the table -- it makes the answers more consistent, if nothing else.  It is a surprisingly common mistake that people make.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As xQbert pointed out, depends on how clean your data is.  Assuming that there is one LostFocus for every GotFocus and that LostFocus EventDateTime is greater than or equal to GotFocus EventDateTime, this should work (fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f36a4/14):

```
WITH cteGotFocus
AS
(
  SELECT  AppID,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AppID ORDER BY EventDateTime) AS RID,
          EventDateTime
  FROM    Table1
  WHERE   EventName = 'GotFocus'
),
cteLostFocus
AS
(
  SELECT  AppID,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY AppID ORDER BY EventDateTime) AS RID,
          EventDateTime
  FROM    Table1
  WHERE   EventName = 'LostFocus'
)

SELECT   SUM(DATEDIFF(s, gf.EventDateTime, lf.EventDateTime)) AS Duration,
         gf.AppID
FROM     cteGotFocus gf INNER JOIN cteLostFocus lf
         ON gf.AppID = lf.AppID AND
            gf.RID = lf.RID
GROUP BY  gf.AppID
ORDER BY  gf.AppID;
```

**EDIT:** Just condensing down some of the unnecessary CTEs.  Fiddle link updated.

Comment: Sweet. Thanks VBlades the above code is awesome. Just one concern though. I cannot assume that I'll always have a GotFocus/LostFocus pair logged in the table. It may be possible that the app crashes so I would have GotFocus logged but not LostFocus. How can I modify the above code to "clean up" the extra rows and only consider the pairs?

Comment: @user3795331: No worries.  Can we assume it will always be the last LostFocus we won't have?  If not how do you want to handle the missing times?  Is there a substitute value or something?

Comment: Yes I believe so. I cannot think of a scenario where I would have LostFocus but not GotFocus. We can assume that we'll always have GotFocus and may or may not have LostFocus! In the case where only GotFocus is there, we can ignore that row and only consider the pairs for computing duration.

Comment: @user3795331:  Here's an updated version.  Here's a fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/efb7f/2.  Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I like VBlades' answer (I think it's easier to read), but this might perform a little better:

```
select g.AppId, sum(DATEDIFF(S, g.EventDateTime, l.EventDateTime)) Duration
from Event g
join Event l on g.AppId = l.AppId and g.EventName = 'GotFocus' and l.EventName = 'LostFocus'
where l.EventDateTime = (select MIN(eventDateTime) from Event e3 where e3.AppId = g.AppId and e3.EventName = 'LostFocus' and e3.EventDateTime > g.EventDateTime)
group by g.AppId
order by g.AppId
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf293/2/0)

Comment: This is for smart people, not me. :)  Nice job.

Comment: @VBlades, I'm not that smart.  With that small test set, my answer is only 2% faster than yours.

Answer (score 0):

If the sequence of events is always GF, LF then you could use this query:

```
select y.appid, y.groupnum, datediff(second, y.gotfocus, y.lostfocus) seconds
from (( row_number() over(partition by appid order by eventdatetime) + 1) / 2 as groupnum,
appid, eventname, eventdatetime
from dbo.mytable) x
pivot( max(x.eventdatetime) for x.eventname in ([gotfocus], [lostfocus]) y
```

Note: I've not tested this solution.

Answer (score -1):

I have taken the same scenario though with different data types and answer which is simple to read is below

```
select kk.bb - jj.aa from
(
    select a , eventname ,sum(c) as aa
    from #tem1
    where eventname = 'login'
    group by a,eventname
) as jj

join 
(
    select a , eventname ,sum(c) as bb
    from #tem1
    where eventname = 'logoff'
    group by a,eventname
) as kk
on jj.a = kk.a
```