# SQL Time Parameter Calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am newbie to SQL who's trying to create an activity report, I have stored procedure and a trigger on a table to record Login and Logout date/time.

[image: SQL Table Image]

I am after some advice on how to calculate time worked from first log in to last log out per day?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Comment: To get the best help from this community would be great if you could tell us, what SQL database are you using, share your current code and explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am using SQL 2008 R2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL script to calculate time difference between multiple rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518781/t-sql-script-to-calculate-time-difference-between-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.*,
       DATEDIFF(second,B.firstloginonthatday,B.lastlogoutonthatday) AS time_elapsed
  FROM  YourTable A
INNER JOIN 
    (        SELECT Z.USERID,
                   CONVERT(DATE,Z.DATE_TIME ) AS ONLYDATE,
                   MIN( Z.DATE_TIME ) AS firstloginonthatday,
                   MAX( Z.DATE_TIME ) AS lastlogoutonthatday  
              FROM  
                (
                    SELECT  *,
                            ROW_NUMBER( )
                            OVER 
                            ( PARTITION BY USERID,CONVERT(DATE,DATE_TIME) ORDER BY CASE WHEN action = 'logout' THEN DATE_TIME 
                              ELSE NULL END
                             ) AS lastlogout_rn,            
                            ROW_NUMBER( )
                            OVER 
                            ( PARTITION BY USERID,CONVERT(DATE,DATE_TIME) ORDER BY CASE WHEN action = 'login' THEN DATE_TIME 
                              ELSE NULL END
                             ) AS firstlogin_rn     
                      FROM Yourtable
                 ) Z
           WHERE Z.lastlogout_rn = 1 OR Z.firstlogin_rn = 1
           GROUP BY Z.USERID,CONVERT(DATE,Z.DATE_TIME )
    ) B
   ON A.USERID = B.USERID
  AND CONVERT(DATE,A.DATE_TIME) = B.ONLYDATE;
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the code, it's much appreciated. For some reason the time calculation for 20170418 is incorrect, I am assuming it could be due to the multiple log in and out, as it's correct for the 20170419?